# How to ignore an XML element in the XQuery output?

Tags: xml, expression, xquery

I have an XML file. I need to get all the elements in the file except one. Need to write it in XQuery. What is the expression?

My file is doc1.xml has:

```
<root>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
  <three>3</three>
</root>
```

If I do fn:doc(doc1.xml) it will return everything.
I want all the information except the element value of 3.
How do I do this?

Comment: You need to do a recursive copy of the tree along the lines suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846779/xquery-update-question/5979002 , skipping the unwanted node (rather than processing it) when you get to it.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the document through a function that uses a typeswitch, doing nothing for the `three` element, and copying all other content.

```
declare function local:filter($nodes as node()*)
{
 for $node in $nodes
 return 
    typeswitch($node)
        case element(three)
            return ()
        case element()
            return 
                element { name($node) } {
                    $node/@*, 
                    local:filter($node/node())
                }
        default 
            return $node
};

let $doc := 
  <root>
    <one>1</one>
    <two>2</two>
    <three>3</three>
  </root>

return local:filter($doc)
```